# How to access JSON-object with multiple values per key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

At the moment I am stuck with a problem that just seems stupid, but I don't know the answer to it.

I am trying to access this JSON-object:

```
 var custom_fields = 
 {
   "28246": 5123,5124,5125
 }
```

I would like to get each value from that key. I would know how to access it if it was a nested-object, but it isn't sadly (it is coming from an API, which I can't change the JSON-response from sadly)

What I tried already is the following:

```
for (var key in custom_fields) {
   if (custom_fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + custom_fields[key]);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the result will be like this:

```
1 -> 5
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> 3
5 -> ,
6 -> 5
...etc...
```

Any suggestions are welcome, I am trying to access it in javascript/Jquery.

Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: It's just not a correct json

Comment: @Faly I thought so too, but there has to be an alternative way, for example concatenating the results separated by the comma's. Would you know how?

Comment: If the part 5123,5124,5125 is a string like "5123,5124,5125", we can do something

Comment: Is your variable 'custom_fields' an accurate example of the JSON received from the API? The three integers should be an array.

Comment: @Faly yes it was, little mistake there sorry. Thanks for helping anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the data is in this format (note the string literals):

```
var custom_fields = { 
   "28246": "5123,5124,5125" 
}
```

If that is the case, you can use [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
In your case, it would be something like this:

```
const values = custom_fields['28246'].split(',');
```

The values of they key `28246` are now stored in the new variable `values` as an array:

```
['5123','5124','5125']
```

If you want to parse all values to integers, I suggest using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const valuesAsInt = custom_fields['28246'].split(',').map(value => parseInt(value);
```

Which will lead to this:

```
[5123, 5124, 5125]
```

Disclaimer: When using newer ECMAScript features such as Array.map, be sure to either use a browser which supports this our include a polyfill.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am ashamed that I forgot about the .split() method. Anyways, should I report this as a mistake in the API, what do you think?

Comment: If the list of values is not wrapped in string literals, it is not valid JSON (you can easily check with tools like jsonlint.com) and therefore definitely a mistake in the API.

Comment: Hi I have a similar issues but i have strings as vales e.g ['yes, allowed', 'no, not allowed']. The issue is my values also contain commas and split just splits the individual values too. Any ideas how can i avoid it? Thank you @glutengo

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by using split function which will convert it into an array and then get the values from that array as below code.

```
var data = {
  "28246": '5123,5124,5125'
}
var arr = data['28246'].split(',');
$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would accept if i could accept 2 answers, because this one is correct as well

Answer (score 0):

You can split by ',' and transform each element to integer by using array.map and '+' operator:

```js
 var custom_fields = 
 {
   "28246": "5123,5124,5125"
 }

custom_fields["28246"] = custom_fields["28246"].split(',').map(el => +el);
console.log(custom_fields);
console.log(custom_fields["28246"][0], custom_fields["28246"][1], custom_fields["28246"][2]);
```